# Why can you comment on some questions/answers but not all of them?

Tags: support, comments

OK, so I haven't been using the Stack Exchange websites long. However when I have been using them, I've noticed that sometimes you can comment and sometimes you can't.

For example, I just went to comment a question to ask for more details because the question wasn't clear, however the only option other than provide an answer was `flag`.

Normally there is `Flag | Comment | Edit | Delete` or something along those lines.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong, is it a site bug, or is it done on purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean `add comment`?  Because usually that is below that line.  Also, is the question closed? Which question is it?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! I hope you enjoy your time here, and that you don't mind too much that I fixed up some of your spelling and grammar.

Comment: Not at all, I am a gamer, what do you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can read in the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) you can only comment once you reach 50 rep. However, it also states:

> you can always comment on your
>   questions and answers, and any answers
>   to questions you've asked, even with 1
>   rep.

Comment: also, if you link your accounts (by using the same OpenID, or doing it manually), you get a free one time 100 rep bonus if you have 200+ rep on another stack exchange site

Comment: Thanks for this, will vote up and accept in 10 minutes when it allows me. Thanks