# Why can't I comment on others' answers? Does it have something to do with reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can you comment on some questions/answers but not all of them?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/834/why-can-you-comment-on-some-questions-answers-but-not-all-of-them)

I can only comment on my own post, not others.

Comment: Okay, migrating it here just to close it as a dupe might have been a bit redundant, but whatever.

Comment: @lunboks I'd probably call it more *bureaucratic* versus *redundant* (the closures served somewhat different purposes).